# How to get back recoded audio from sphinx4

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

Hi I am trying to get the audio file from sphinx4, is there any way to save audiofile to local? let see user say "OK sphinx tell me time " I need to save audio file witch contain "ok sphinx4 tell me time " syntax, so i can use this audio file for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you can get back audio file from decoder

```
    recognizer = SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup()
            .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
            .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
            .getRecognizer();

    recognizer.addListener(mRecognitionListener);
    recognizer.getDecoder().setRawdataSize(300000);// don't forget to set size

    recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);


}
```

and then inside your onResult callback

```
@override
public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
Log.d(TAG, "onResult: " + + recognizer.getDecoder().getRawdata().length);

        if (hypothesis != null) {
            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        }
      Decoder decoder= recognizer.getDecoder();
        short[] data = decoder.getRawdata();
        try {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Utils.getPublicStorageDir("recoding",".raw")));
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                dos.writeShort(data[i]);
            }
            dos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And you can play this audio

```
   public static void playAudioFromRaw(short[] data){
        int bufsize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
                8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
        );
        AudioTrack trackplayer = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                bufsize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM
        );
        trackplayer.play();
        trackplayer.write(data, 0, data.length);
        trackplayer.stop();
        trackplayer.release();
    }
```